# Excel posix time

Tags: excel, posix, epoch

Is there a way in Microsoft Excel to convert the regular date to epoch (posix) time? I am trying to store allm y times as doubles in the database and I need to firstly convert the dates in csv files I have.

Comment: let me know if my answer helps and if not let me know as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=(A1-25569)*86400
```

got this from here:

http://untangible.com/2009/01/covert-unix-epoch-dates-in-microsoft-excel-including-timezone-examples.html

Comment: checked on a few examples and it seems to be OK. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I confirm it, this is working for me to
row.Cells(, colTimestamp) = JSON("timestamp") / 86400 + 25569

You can also implement a formula in excel to perform the conversion
FechaPosix - =(I2/86400)+DATE(1970;1;1)