# Get Unix time milliseconds

Tags: vba, excel, datetime

In Java to get system time in milliseconds I use:

```
 new date().gettime()
```

It is possible to get the same result in milliseconds using Excel VBA?

Comment: Why do you want the system time in milliseconds?

Comment: Because in one second i can post > 1 times and i need control time of each post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SUMMARY: For best results, use `GetSystemTime`.

The Excel worksheet function `Now()` has relatively good precision, roughly down to 10 ms. But to call it you have to use a worksheet formula.

To correctly get the milliseconds value, you should **avoid** the VBA `Now()` function. Its precision is roughly 1 second.

The VBA `Timer()` function returns a `single` with a precision of roughly 5 milliseconds. But you have to use `Now()` to get the date part. This might cause a slight problem if `Now()` is called **before** midnight and `Timer()` is called **after** midnight (this is probably a rare situation and not an issue for most people).

The Windows API function [GetSystemTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has true millisecond precision. You can use the values in the [SYSTEMTIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950(v=vs.85).aspx) structure to create an Excel double that has the correct millisecond precision. GetSystemTime returns the UTC time so if you want the date in POSIX format, you can subtract the UNIX epoch (1 January 1970 UTC), which is 25569 in Excel date format (disregarding leap seconds).

The code below compares the precision of each method:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type SYSTEMTIME
    wYear As Integer
    wMonth As Integer
    wDayOfWeek As Integer
    wDay As Integer
    wHour As Integer
    wMinute As Integer
    wSecond As Integer
    wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type

Private Declare Sub GetSystemTime Lib "kernel32" (lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME)

Function Now_System() As Double
    Dim st As SYSTEMTIME
    GetSystemTime st
    Now_System = DateSerial(st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay) + _
        TimeSerial(st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond) + _
        st.wMilliseconds / 86400000#
End Function

Function Now_Timer() As Double
    Now_Timer = CDbl(Int(Now)) + CDbl(Timer() / 86400#)
End Function


Sub CompareCurrentTimeFunctions()
    ' Compare precision of different methods to get current time.
    Me.Range("A1:D1000").NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd h:mm:ss.000"

    Dim d As Double
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 1000
        ' 1) Excel NOW() formula returns same value until delay of ~10 milliseconds. (local time)
        Me.Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=Now()"
        d = Me.Cells(1, 1)
        Me.Cells(i, 1) = d

        ' 2) VBA Now() returns same value until delay of ~1 second. (local time)
        d = Now
        Me.Cells(i, 2) = d

        ' 3) VBA Timer returns same value until delay of ~5 milliseconds. (local time)
        Me.Cells(i, 3) = Now_Timer

        ' 4) System time is precise down to 1 millisecond. (UTC)
        Me.Cells(i, 4) = Now_System
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Different interpretation, based on [Excel posix time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722804/excel-posix-time/10722885#10722885) and with an hour adjustment for summer time:

```
Sub Pose()
    ut = ((Now - 25569) * 86400000) - 3600000
End Sub
```

If not sufficiently precise, http://vbadud.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/excel-vba-timestamp-milliseconds-using.html may be of interest.

Comment: No result is not same!!! As Your example returns always 000 on the end, and your link return not number string as i need

Comment: Good enought but last digit always = 0

Comment: VBA Now() does not return a valid milliseconds part. See my answer for details.

Comment: @pnuts: Yes when I say "not valid" I mean that the value is inaccurate. There is possible confusion because a double-precision number **can** hold an Excel time value which is accurate down to milliseconds (see my answer). But VBA's Now() function returns the same value until a delay of roughly 1 whole second. In my answer, I run a loop to demonstrate this limitation.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a short extension on the answer by @bouvierr as I needed the equivalent of the java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() method in VBA:

```
Private Type SYSTEMTIME
    wYear As Integer
    wMonth As Integer
    wDayOfWeek As Integer
    wDay As Integer
    wHour As Integer
    wMinute As Integer
    wSecond As Integer
    wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type

Private Declare Sub GetSystemTime Lib "kernel32" (lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME)

Function CurrentTimeMillis() As Double
    ' Returns the milliseconds from 1970/01/01 00:00:00.0 to system UTC
    Dim st As SYSTEMTIME
    GetSystemTime st
    Dim t_Start, t_Now
    t_Start = DateSerial(1970, 1, 1) ' Starting time for Linux
    t_Now = DateSerial(st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay) + _
        TimeSerial(st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond)
    CurrentTimeMillis = DateDiff("s", t_Start, t_Now) * 1000 + st.wMilliseconds
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This produces a timestamp in format `yyyy mm dd hh:mm:ss.fff` where `fff` are the milliseconds.

```
Dim dateToday As Date
Dim datetimeNow As Date
Dim secondsElapsedSinceMidnight As Double
Dim h As Long
Dim m As Long
Dim s As Long

dateToday = Now
secondsElapsedSinceMidnight = Timer

h = Int(secondsElapsedSinceMidnight / 3600)
m = Int(secondsElapsedSinceMidnight / 60) - h * 60
s = Int(secondsElapsedSinceMidnight) - m * 60 - h * 3600

datetimeNow = DateSerial(Year(dateToday), Month(dateToday), Day(dateToday)) _
    + TimeSerial(h, m, s)

Debug.Print Format(datetimeNow, "yyyy mm dd hh:nn:ss.") _
    & Format((secondsElapsedSinceMidnight _
      - Int(secondsElapsedSinceMidnight)) * 1000, "000")
```

As I submit this answer, the output is:

```
2015 04 21 16:24:22.852
```

Answer (score 1):

I found only one possible variant

```
Private Type SYSTEMTIME
        wYear As Integer
        wMonth As Integer
        wDayOfWeek As Integer
        wDay As Integer
        wHour As Integer
        wMinute As Integer
        wSecond As Integer
        wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type

Private Declare Sub GetLocalTime Lib "kernel32" (lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME)
Sub test()
Dim sSysTime As SYSTEMTIME

GetLocalTime sSysTime

MsgBox = ((Now - 25569) * 86400000) - 3600000 + sSysTime.wMilliseconds
End Sub
```

Comment: You should avoid using two different functions to get the time. You will have inconsistencies between the two results. To get better results, use just the SYSTEMTIME structure.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work well:

```
Format(Now, "h:mm:ss") & Right(Format(Timer, "0.000"), 4)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).